# Normal running instantiating prefabs are now stuck at given position and not moving anymore

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics, instantiation

Instantiated objects are stuck at initial position while it was working just normally with no change in code.

I am making a spaceship based game and i was able to making instantiation of prefabs normally until i started adding layers so that the instantiated objects of different kind do not collide. But meanwhile when i ran the game my instantiating objects got stuck at the starting location of their launch.

[image: Code for Bullet instantiation]
[image: Stuck at initial position]

Comment: Please add your code as text, not as an image.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You probably messed up your Layers a little bit.

To fix this problem go to the Physics 2D Manager (Edit > Project Settings > Physics 2D).

At the bottom you can see the layer collision matrix. (The fancy looking thing with checkboxes)

Because I don't know which layers you have I'm using "Player" as the layer for your player spaceship and "PlayerBullets" as the layer for the bullets your spaceship shoots.

You can now disable collision between the player layer and the player bullet layer.

If your enemies can also shoot, I would create a new Layer called "Bullets". The player layer should be able to collide with enemy bullets, but not with its own bullets.